# Parent and child categories with their id in drop_down in CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

How to build your custom drop-down with their id(s) to show your CPT(custom post type) with custom tax categories in WordPress child template

Comment: where you are using custom drop-down?

Comment: @Latheesh V M Villa, at admin side

Comment: sorry  you have provided very less details..better add up as much detail possible so that someone could answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin "advanced-custom-post-search"

With Change in file "acps-results_loop"

```
    <?php
   register_nav_menus(array(
        // Added primary again, only for make sequence (theme location) in page:nav-menus.php at admin side
        'primary' => 'Primary Menu',
        // Second Menu
        'secondary' => 'Secondary Menu',
        // Third Menu
        'quickLinks' => 'Quick Links',
    ));


    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'websiteAssetsBootstrapOnly');
```